# Laravel 5.2 Vendor Package Traits

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5, autoload

I've installed and configured-
https://github.com/Propaganistas/Laravel-FakeId

Coded the following-

routes.php

```
Route::model('orange', 'App\Orange'); Route::resource('orange', 'OrangeController');
```

Orange.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Propaganistas\LaravalFakeId\FakeIdTrait;
class Orange extends Model
{

use FakeIdTrait;

protected $fillable = ['orange_name'];
}
```

When I load- http://localhost:8000/orange/3

I received the following -

`FatalErrorException in Orange.php line 10: Trait 'Propaganistas\LaravalFakeId\FakeIdTrait' not foun`d

I don't think I've used traits in vendor packages before- normally I define in the App folder. Is there some kind of config etc I need to set up to enable this to work?

My composer json is-

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "propaganistas/laravel-fakeid": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the ServerProvider and the Facade in your `config/app`

Comment: Thanks. Yes to service provider-   `Propaganistas\LaravelFakeId\FakeIdServiceProvider::class,` No to facade because only invoked using service provider.  Any other ideas?

Comment: It's a typo: You typoed "Laraval", it should be "Laravel". `use Propaganistas\LaravalFakeId\FakeIdTrait;` is wrong. If it works, you can delete your question, typo answers are not very useful on StackOverflow.

Comment: wow thanks. Can't believe it!